# Save october CMS formWidget data to database table

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-plugins, octobercms-widgets

I have a plugin and I have included a FormWidget to that with some fields. those are in a partial. When i click create I can see the fields from the partial via the FormWidget but I am not sure how I can save values form those fields to db. What method do i need to call from the FormWidget class in order to save data to a model?

Answer (score 2):

Found it,

in the Formwidget class override the default function like this.

```
public function getSaveValue($value)
{
    return $value;
}
```

for more info.
https://octobercms.com/docs/backend/widgets
under "Saving form data"